# Setting schedule task for windows update restart

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, restart

How would I go about setting a Windows 2012 Server up to restart when Windows Updates/Patches have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2835627) should help get started.It uses a reg key to update settings
Snippet from the link Above:
Create a reg key as below:

```
Registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU 
Value: AlwaysAutoRebootAtScheduledTime 
Type: REG_DWORD 
Value data: 0 (default value) or 1 (force a restart)
```